# how to parse stdout of imagick identify?

Tags: parsing, imagemagick-identify

when i run

```
wget -q -O- 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png' | magick identify -verbose -
```

i get

```
Image: /tmp/magick-25620GqQdCVSm3pGs
  Base filename: -
  Format: PNG (Portable Network Graphics)
  Mime type: image/png
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 158x158+0+0
  Units: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Type: PaletteAlpha
  Base type: Undefined
  Endianess: Undefined
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 8-bit
    green: 8-bit
    blue: 8-bit
    alpha: 8-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 24964
    Red:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 204.299 (0.801172)
      standard deviation: 97.6901 (0.383099)
      kurtosis: 0.551289
      skewness: -1.57203
      entropy: 0.667467
    Green:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 194.141 (0.761339)
      standard deviation: 99.0545 (0.388449)
      kurtosis: -0.185686
      skewness: -1.24476
      entropy: 0.667467
    Blue:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 186.122 (0.729891)
      standard deviation: 107.453 (0.421384)
      kurtosis: -0.905696
      skewness: -1.00834
      entropy: 0.667467
    Alpha:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 31.3143 (0.122801)
      standard deviation: 82.6297 (0.324038)
      kurtosis: 3.32656
      skewness: 2.29819
      entropy: 0.103191
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 153.969 (0.603801)
      standard deviation: 96.7068 (0.379243)
      kurtosis: -1.75376
      skewness: -0.433616
      entropy: 0.526398
  Alpha: srgba(255,255,255,0)   #FFFFFF00
  Colors: 215
  Histogram:
      4567: (  0,  0,  0,  0) #00000000 none
      1152: (188,187,187,255) #BCBBBBFF srgba(188,187,187,1)
      1672: (244,128, 36,255) #F48024FF srgba(244,128,36,1)
        14: (244,128, 36,  1) #F4802401 srgba(244,128,36,0.00392157)
         9: (244,128, 36,  3) #F4802403 srgba(244,128,36,0.0117647)
         8: (244,128, 36,  4) #F4802404 srgba(244,128,36,0.0156863)
         8: (244,128, 36,247) #F48024F7 srgba(244,128,36,0.968627)
         7: (244,128, 36,  2) #F4802402 srgba(244,128,36,0.00784314)
         6: (244,128, 36, 12) #F480240C srgba(244,128,36,0.0470588)
         6: (244,128, 36,136) #F4802488 srgba(244,128,36,0.533333)
         6: (244,128, 36,248) #F48024F8 srgba(244,128,36,0.972549)
         6: (244,128, 36,250) #F48024FA srgba(244,128,36,0.980392)
         6: (244,128, 36, 11) #F480240B srgba(244,128,36,0.0431373)
         5: (244,128, 36,249) #F48024F9 srgba(244,128,36,0.976471)
         5: (244,128, 36,236) #F48024EC srgba(244,128,36,0.92549)
         5: (244,128, 36,232) #F48024E8 srgba(244,128,36,0.909804)
         5: (244,128, 36,252) #F48024FC srgba(244,128,36,0.988235)
         5: (244,128, 36, 13) #F480240D srgba(244,128,36,0.0509804)
         5: (244,128, 36,211) #F48024D3 srgba(244,128,36,0.827451)
         5: (244,128, 36,  9) #F4802409 srgba(244,128,36,0.0352941)
         5: (244,128, 36,254) #F48024FE srgba(244,128,36,0.996078)
         5: (244,128, 36, 77) #F480244D srgba(244,128,36,0.301961)
         5: (244,128, 36,253) #F48024FD srgba(244,128,36,0.992157)
         5: (244,128, 36, 58) #F480243A srgba(244,128,36,0.227451)
         4: (244,128, 36, 91) #F480245B srgba(244,128,36,0.356863)
         4: (244,128, 36,  6) #F4802406 srgba(244,128,36,0.0235294)
         4: (244,128, 36,230) #F48024E6 srgba(244,128,36,0.901961)
         4: (244,128, 36, 40) #F4802428 srgba(244,128,36,0.156863)
         4: (244,128, 36, 52) #F4802434 srgba(244,128,36,0.203922)
         4: (244,128, 36, 93) #F480245D srgba(244,128,36,0.364706)
         4: (244,128, 36,226) #F48024E2 srgba(244,128,36,0.886275)
         4: (244,128, 36, 24) #F4802418 srgba(244,128,36,0.0941176)
         4: (244,128, 36,148) #F4802494 srgba(244,128,36,0.580392)
         4: (244,128, 36, 28) #F480241C srgba(244,128,36,0.109804)
         4: (244,128, 36,104) #F4802468 srgba(244,128,36,0.407843)
         4: (244,128, 36, 30) #F480241E srgba(244,128,36,0.117647)
         4: (244,128, 36,183) #F48024B7 srgba(244,128,36,0.717647)
         4: (244,128, 36, 15) #F480240F srgba(244,128,36,0.0588235)
         4: (244,128, 36,234) #F48024EA srgba(244,128,36,0.917647)
         4: (244,128, 36, 69) #F4802445 srgba(244,128,36,0.270588)
         4: (244,128, 36,233) #F48024E9 srgba(244,128,36,0.913725)
         3: (244,128, 36,170) #F48024AA srgba(244,128,36,0.666667)
         3: (244,128, 36,231) #F48024E7 srgba(244,128,36,0.905882)
         3: (244,128, 36,160) #F48024A0 srgba(244,128,36,0.627451)
         3: (244,128, 36, 54) #F4802436 srgba(244,128,36,0.211765)
         3: (244,128, 36, 56) #F4802438 srgba(244,128,36,0.219608)
         3: (244,128, 36, 89) #F4802459 srgba(244,128,36,0.34902)
         3: (244,128, 36,141) #F480248D srgba(244,128,36,0.552941)
         3: (244,128, 36, 88) #F4802458 srgba(244,128,36,0.345098)
         3: (244,128, 36,134) #F4802486 srgba(244,128,36,0.52549)
         3: (244,128, 36,220) #F48024DC srgba(244,128,36,0.862745)
         3: (244,128, 36,131) #F4802483 srgba(244,128,36,0.513725)
         3: (244,128, 36, 96) #F4802460 srgba(244,128,36,0.376471)
         3: (244,128, 36,117) #F4802475 srgba(244,128,36,0.458824)
         3: (244,128, 36,122) #F480247A srgba(244,128,36,0.478431)
         3: (244,128, 36,216) #F48024D8 srgba(244,128,36,0.847059)
         3: (244,128, 36, 10) #F480240A srgba(244,128,36,0.0392157)
         3: (244,128, 36,208) #F48024D0 srgba(244,128,36,0.815686)
         3: (244,128, 36,206) #F48024CE srgba(244,128,36,0.807843)
         3: (244,128, 36,207) #F48024CF srgba(244,128,36,0.811765)
         3: (244,128, 36,205) #F48024CD srgba(244,128,36,0.803922)
         3: (244,128, 36, 14) #F480240E srgba(244,128,36,0.054902)
         3: (244,128, 36,238) #F48024EE srgba(244,128,36,0.933333)
         3: (244,128, 36, 20) #F4802414 srgba(244,128,36,0.0784314)
         3: (244,128, 36,196) #F48024C4 srgba(244,128,36,0.768627)
         3: (244,128, 36, 21) #F4802415 srgba(244,128,36,0.0823529)
         3: (244,128, 36, 26) #F480241A srgba(244,128,36,0.101961)
         3: (244,128, 36,189) #F48024BD srgba(244,128,36,0.741176)
         3: (244,128, 36,188) #F48024BC srgba(244,128,36,0.737255)
         3: (244,128, 36, 31) #F480241F srgba(244,128,36,0.121569)
         3: (244,128, 36, 32) #F4802420 srgba(244,128,36,0.12549)
         3: (244,128, 36, 33) #F4802421 srgba(244,128,36,0.129412)
         3: (244,128, 36,177) #F48024B1 srgba(244,128,36,0.694118)
         3: (244,128, 36,175) #F48024AF srgba(244,128,36,0.686275)
         3: (244,128, 36, 37) #F4802425 srgba(244,128,36,0.145098)
         3: (244,128, 36,173) #F48024AD srgba(244,128,36,0.678431)
         3: (244,128, 36, 45) #F480242D srgba(244,128,36,0.176471)
         2: (244,128, 36,163) #F48024A3 srgba(244,128,36,0.639216)
         2: (244,128, 36,251) #F48024FB srgba(244,128,36,0.984314)
         2: (244,128, 36,246) #F48024F6 srgba(244,128,36,0.964706)
         2: (244,128, 36,244) #F48024F4 srgba(244,128,36,0.956863)
         2: (244,128, 36,245) #F48024F5 srgba(244,128,36,0.960784)
         2: (244,128, 36,240) #F48024F0 srgba(244,128,36,0.941176)
         2: (244,128, 36,239) #F48024EF srgba(244,128,36,0.937255)
         2: (244,128, 36,237) #F48024ED srgba(244,128,36,0.929412)
         2: (244,128, 36,229) #F48024E5 srgba(244,128,36,0.898039)
         2: (244,128, 36,223) #F48024DF srgba(244,128,36,0.87451)
         2: (244,128, 36,221) #F48024DD srgba(244,128,36,0.866667)
         2: (244,128, 36,219) #F48024DB srgba(244,128,36,0.858824)
         2: (244,128, 36,217) #F48024D9 srgba(244,128,36,0.85098)
         2: (244,128, 36,214) #F48024D6 srgba(244,128,36,0.839216)
         2: (244,128, 36,213) #F48024D5 srgba(244,128,36,0.835294)
         2: (244,128, 36,209) #F48024D1 srgba(244,128,36,0.819608)
         2: (244,128, 36,201) #F48024C9 srgba(244,128,36,0.788235)
         2: (244,128, 36,198) #F48024C6 srgba(244,128,36,0.776471)
         2: (244,128, 36,192) #F48024C0 srgba(244,128,36,0.752941)
         2: (244,128, 36,186) #F48024BA srgba(244,128,36,0.729412)
         2: (244,128, 36,181) #F48024B5 srgba(244,128,36,0.709804)
         2: (244,128, 36,179) #F48024B3 srgba(244,128,36,0.701961)
         2: (244,128, 36,176) #F48024B0 srgba(244,128,36,0.690196)
         2: (244,128, 36,172) #F48024AC srgba(244,128,36,0.67451)
         2: (244,128, 36,168) #F48024A8 srgba(244,128,36,0.658824)
         2: (244,128, 36,166) #F48024A6 srgba(244,128,36,0.65098)
         2: (244,128, 36,156) #F480249C srgba(244,128,36,0.611765)
         2: (244,128, 36,152) #F4802498 srgba(244,128,36,0.596078)
         2: (244,128, 36,147) #F4802493 srgba(244,128,36,0.576471)
         2: (244,128, 36,144) #F4802490 srgba(244,128,36,0.564706)
         2: (244,128, 36,135) #F4802487 srgba(244,128,36,0.529412)
         2: (244,128, 36,132) #F4802484 srgba(244,128,36,0.517647)
         2: (244,128, 36,128) #F4802480 srgba(244,128,36,0.501961)
         2: (244,128, 36,124) #F480247C srgba(244,128,36,0.486275)
         2: (244,128, 36,120) #F4802478 srgba(244,128,36,0.470588)
         2: (244,128, 36,114) #F4802472 srgba(244,128,36,0.447059)
         2: (244,128, 36,106) #F480246A srgba(244,128,36,0.415686)
         2: (244,128, 36,100) #F4802464 srgba(244,128,36,0.392157)
         2: (244,128, 36, 99) #F4802463 srgba(244,128,36,0.388235)
         2: (244,128, 36, 94) #F480245E srgba(244,128,36,0.368627)
         2: (244,128, 36, 86) #F4802456 srgba(244,128,36,0.337255)
         2: (244,128, 36, 82) #F4802452 srgba(244,128,36,0.321569)
         2: (244,128, 36, 70) #F4802446 srgba(244,128,36,0.27451)
         2: (244,128, 36, 67) #F4802443 srgba(244,128,36,0.262745)
         2: (244,128, 36, 63) #F480243F srgba(244,128,36,0.247059)
         2: (244,128, 36, 62) #F480243E srgba(244,128,36,0.243137)
         2: (244,128, 36, 60) #F480243C srgba(244,128,36,0.235294)
         2: (244,128, 36, 59) #F480243B srgba(244,128,36,0.231373)
         2: (244,128, 36, 53) #F4802435 srgba(244,128,36,0.207843)
         2: (244,128, 36, 51) #F4802433 srgba(244,128,36,0.2)
         2: (244,128, 36, 50) #F4802432 srgba(244,128,36,0.196078)
         2: (244,128, 36, 47) #F480242F srgba(244,128,36,0.184314)
         2: (244,128, 36, 36) #F4802424 srgba(244,128,36,0.141176)
         2: (244,128, 36, 35) #F4802423 srgba(244,128,36,0.137255)
         2: (244,128, 36, 27) #F480241B srgba(244,128,36,0.105882)
         2: (244,128, 36, 18) #F4802412 srgba(244,128,36,0.0705882)
         2: (244,128, 36, 17) #F4802411 srgba(244,128,36,0.0666667)
         2: (244,128, 36, 16) #F4802410 srgba(244,128,36,0.0627451)
         2: (244,128, 36,  7) #F4802407 srgba(244,128,36,0.027451)
         2: (244,128, 36,  5) #F4802405 srgba(244,128,36,0.0196078)
         1: (244,128, 36, 87) #F4802457 srgba(244,128,36,0.341176)
         1: (244,128, 36, 84) #F4802454 srgba(244,128,36,0.329412)
         1: (244,128, 36, 85) #F4802455 srgba(244,128,36,0.333333)
         1: (244,128, 36, 19) #F4802413 srgba(244,128,36,0.0745098)
         1: (244,128, 36, 83) #F4802453 srgba(244,128,36,0.32549)
         1: (244,128, 36, 81) #F4802451 srgba(244,128,36,0.317647)
         1: (244,128, 36, 78) #F480244E srgba(244,128,36,0.305882)
         1: (244,128, 36,145) #F4802491 srgba(244,128,36,0.568627)
         1: (244,128, 36, 76) #F480244C srgba(244,128,36,0.298039)
         1: (244,128, 36, 75) #F480244B srgba(244,128,36,0.294118)
         1: (244,128, 36, 73) #F4802449 srgba(244,128,36,0.286275)
         1: (244,128, 36, 72) #F4802448 srgba(244,128,36,0.282353)
         1: (244,128, 36, 71) #F4802447 srgba(244,128,36,0.278431)
         1: (244,128, 36,241) #F48024F1 srgba(244,128,36,0.945098)
         1: (244,128, 36, 68) #F4802444 srgba(244,128,36,0.266667)
         1: (244,128, 36,146) #F4802492 srgba(244,128,36,0.572549)
         1: (244,128, 36,243) #F48024F3 srgba(244,128,36,0.952941)
         1: (244,128, 36, 66) #F4802442 srgba(244,128,36,0.258824)
         1: (244,128, 36, 64) #F4802440 srgba(244,128,36,0.25098)
         1: (244,128, 36, 65) #F4802441 srgba(244,128,36,0.254902)
         1: (244,128, 36,200) #F48024C8 srgba(244,128,36,0.784314)
         1: (244,128, 36,203) #F48024CB srgba(244,128,36,0.796078)
         1: (244,128, 36, 61) #F480243D srgba(244,128,36,0.239216)
         1: (244,128, 36,202) #F48024CA srgba(244,128,36,0.792157)
         1: (244,128, 36,204) #F48024CC srgba(244,128,36,0.8)
         1: (244,128, 36,150) #F4802496 srgba(244,128,36,0.588235)
         1: (244,128, 36, 57) #F4802439 srgba(244,128,36,0.223529)
         1: (244,128, 36,153) #F4802499 srgba(244,128,36,0.6)
         1: (244,128, 36,154) #F480249A srgba(244,128,36,0.603922)
         1: (244,128, 36, 55) #F4802437 srgba(244,128,36,0.215686)
         1: (244,128, 36,165) #F48024A5 srgba(244,128,36,0.647059)
         1: (244,128, 36,210) #F48024D2 srgba(244,128,36,0.823529)
         1: (244,128, 36,212) #F48024D4 srgba(244,128,36,0.831373)
         1: (244,128, 36,  8) #F4802408 srgba(244,128,36,0.0313725)
         1: (244,128, 36, 48) #F4802430 srgba(244,128,36,0.188235)
         1: (244,128, 36, 46) #F480242E srgba(244,128,36,0.180392)
         1: (244,128, 36,215) #F48024D7 srgba(244,128,36,0.843137)
         1: (244,128, 36,169) #F48024A9 srgba(244,128,36,0.662745)
         1: (244,128, 36, 42) #F480242A srgba(244,128,36,0.164706)
         1: (244,128, 36, 43) #F480242B srgba(244,128,36,0.168627)
         1: (244,128, 36,171) #F48024AB srgba(244,128,36,0.670588)
         1: (244,128, 36, 39) #F4802427 srgba(244,128,36,0.152941)
         1: (244,128, 36,242) #F48024F2 srgba(244,128,36,0.94902)
         1: (244,128, 36,174) #F48024AE srgba(244,128,36,0.682353)
         1: (244,128, 36,227) #F48024E3 srgba(244,128,36,0.890196)
         1: (244,128, 36, 34) #F4802422 srgba(244,128,36,0.133333)
         1: (244,128, 36,178) #F48024B2 srgba(244,128,36,0.698039)
         1: (244,128, 36,182) #F48024B6 srgba(244,128,36,0.713725)
         1: (244,128, 36,185) #F48024B9 srgba(244,128,36,0.72549)
         1: (244,128, 36,184) #F48024B8 srgba(244,128,36,0.721569)
         1: (244,128, 36,187) #F48024BB srgba(244,128,36,0.733333)
         1: (244,128, 36,190) #F48024BE srgba(244,128,36,0.745098)
         1: (244,128, 36,123) #F480247B srgba(244,128,36,0.482353)
         1: (244,128, 36,228) #F48024E4 srgba(244,128,36,0.894118)
         1: (244,128, 36,118) #F4802476 srgba(244,128,36,0.462745)
         1: (244,128, 36,126) #F480247E srgba(244,128,36,0.494118)
         1: (244,128, 36,193) #F48024C1 srgba(244,128,36,0.756863)
         1: (244,128, 36,112) #F4802470 srgba(244,128,36,0.439216)
         1: (244,128, 36,113) #F4802471 srgba(244,128,36,0.443137)
         1: (244,128, 36,111) #F480246F srgba(244,128,36,0.435294)
         1: (244,128, 36,108) #F480246C srgba(244,128,36,0.423529)
         1: (244,128, 36,109) #F480246D srgba(244,128,36,0.427451)
         1: (244,128, 36, 25) #F4802419 srgba(244,128,36,0.0980392)
         1: (244,128, 36,107) #F480246B srgba(244,128,36,0.419608)
         1: (244,128, 36,129) #F4802481 srgba(244,128,36,0.505882)
         1: (244,128, 36,105) #F4802469 srgba(244,128,36,0.411765)
         1: (244,128, 36,102) #F4802466 srgba(244,128,36,0.4)
         1: (244,128, 36, 22) #F4802416 srgba(244,128,36,0.0862745)
         1: (244,128, 36,101) #F4802465 srgba(244,128,36,0.396078)
         1: (244,128, 36,195) #F48024C3 srgba(244,128,36,0.764706)
         1: (244,128, 36,130) #F4802482 srgba(244,128,36,0.509804)
         1: (244,128, 36,199) #F48024C7 srgba(244,128,36,0.780392)
         1: (244,128, 36,133) #F4802485 srgba(244,128,36,0.521569)
         1: (244,128, 36,139) #F480248B srgba(244,128,36,0.545098)
         1: (244,128, 36, 90) #F480245A srgba(244,128,36,0.352941)
         1: (244,128, 36,138) #F480248A srgba(244,128,36,0.541176)
         1: (244,128, 36,143) #F480248F srgba(244,128,36,0.560784)
     17069: (255,255,255,  0) #FFFFFF00 srgba(255,255,255,0)
  Rendering intent: Perceptual
  Gamma: 0.454545
  Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
  Background color: white
  Border color: srgba(223,223,223,1)
  Matte color: grey74
  Transparent color: none
  Interlace: None
  Intensity: Undefined
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 158x158+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: Zip
  Orientation: Undefined
  Properties:
    date:create: 2019-04-22T14:37:05+02:00
    date:modify: 2019-04-22T14:37:05+02:00
    png:IHDR.bit-depth-orig: 8
    png:IHDR.bit_depth: 8
    png:IHDR.color-type-orig: 6
    png:IHDR.color_type: 6 (RGBA)
    png:IHDR.interlace_method: 0 (Not interlaced)
    png:IHDR.width,height: 158, 158
    png:sRGB: intent=0 (Perceptual Intent)
    png:text: 1 tEXt/zTXt/iTXt chunks were found
    signature: 2e2661f544cee80a0286496a55de16c10bbf412cbeca3c22eb7396e1c549bada
    Software: Adobe ImageReady
  Artifacts:
    filename: -
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 3445B
  Number pixels: 24964
  Pixels per second: 8.32133MB
  User time: 0.000u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.002
  Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-11 Q16 x86_64 2018-09-08 https://www.imagemagick.org
```

but i want to read that programmatically, how am i supposed to parse this? it looks human-friendly, but it doesn't look very computer-parsing-friendly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `-format` option of identify to print this in your own format:

```sh
wget -q -O- 'your://url' | magick identify -format '%[compression]\n%[colorspace]\n' -
```

```
Zip
sRGB
```

You can find the whole list of all available options here: https://imagemagick.org/script/escape.php.

Or you could decide to use json as the output format:

```
wget -q -O- 'your://url' | magick convert - json:-
```

```js
[{
  "image": {
    "name": "-",
    "format": "PNG",
    "formatDescription": "PNG",
    "mimeType": "image/png",
    "class": "DirectClass",
    "geometry": {
      "width": 158,
      "height": 158,
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0
    },
    "units": "Undefined",
    "type": "PaletteAlpha",
    "baseType": "Undefined",
    "endianess": "Undefined",
    "colorspace": "sRGB",
    "depth": 8,
    "baseDepth": 8,
    "channelDepth": {
      "alpha": 8,
      "red": 8,
      "green": 8,
      "blue": 8
    },
    "pixels": 99856,
    "imageStatistics": {
      "Overall": {
        "min": 0,
        "max": 255,
        "mean": 153.969,
        "standardDeviation": 24853.7,
        "kurtosis": -1.75376,
        "skewness": -0.433616,
        "entropy": 0.526398
      }
    },
    "channelStatistics": {
      "Alpha": {
        "min": 0,
        "max": 255,
        "mean": 31.3143,
        "standardDeviation": 21235.8,
        "kurtosis": 3.32656,
        "skewness": 2.29819,
        "entropy": 0.103191
      },
      "Red": {
        "min": 0,
        "max": 255,
        "mean": 204.299,
        "standardDeviation": 25106.4,
        "kurtosis": 0.551289,
        "skewness": -1.57203,
        "entropy": 0.667467
      },
      "Green": {
        "min": 0,
        "max": 255,
        "mean": 194.141,
        "standardDeviation": 25457,
        "kurtosis": -0.185686,
        "skewness": -1.24476,
        "entropy": 0.667467
      },
      "Blue": {
        "min": 0,
        "max": 255,
        "mean": 186.122,
        "standardDeviation": 27615.4,
        "kurtosis": -0.905696,
        "skewness": -1.00834,
        "entropy": 0.667467
      }
    },
    "alpha": "#FFFFFF00",
    "renderingIntent": "Perceptual",
    "gamma": 0.454545,
    "chromaticity": {
      "redPrimary": {
        "x": 0.64,
        "y": 0.33
      },
      "greenPrimary": {
        "x": 0.3,
        "y": 0.6
      },
      "bluePrimary": {
        "x": 0.15,
        "y": 0.06
      },
      "whitePrimary": {
        "x": 0.3127,
        "y": 0.329
      }
    },
    "matteColor": "#BDBDBD",
    "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "borderColor": "#DFDFDF",
    "transparentColor": "#00000000",
    "interlace": "None",
    "intensity": "Undefined",
    "compose": "Over",
    "pageGeometry": {
      "width": 158,
      "height": 158,
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0
    },
    "dispose": "Undefined",
    "iterations": 0,
    "compression": "Zip",
    "orientation": "Undefined",
    "properties": {
      "date:create": "2019-04-22T14:57:00+00:00",
      "date:modify": "2019-04-22T14:57:00+00:00",
      "png:IHDR.bit-depth-orig": "8",
      "png:IHDR.bit_depth": "8",
      "png:IHDR.color-type-orig": "6",
      "png:IHDR.color_type": "6 (RGBA)",
      "png:IHDR.interlace_method": "0 (Not interlaced)",
      "png:IHDR.width,height": "158, 158",
      "png:sRGB": "intent=0 (Perceptual Intent)",
      "png:text": "1 tEXt/zTXt/iTXt chunks were found",
      "signature": "656627774777ffa31c094f674683ff3fe8555efa39e17bedbc7bce587af3c28a",
      "Software": "Adobe ImageReady"
    },
    "tainted": false,
    "filesize": "3445B",
    "numberPixels": "24964",
    "pixelsPerSecond": "3.97541MB",
    "userTime": "0.010u",
    "elapsedTime": "0:01.006",
    "version": "/usr/share/doc/ImageMagick-7//index.html"
  }
}
]
```